# Function overloading and template deduction priority

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, overloading

Consider the following function declaration :

```
template<typename T> f(const T& x); // Version 1
template<typename T1, typename T2> f(const MyClass<T1, T2>& x); // Version 2
```

If I call `f` with a type with no relation with `MyClass`, the first version will be called. If I call `f` with a `MyClass` type (whatever the template parameters type are) then the second version will be called. But now, consider :

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
MyDerivedClass : public MyClass<T1, T2> {};
```

What version of the function will be called for a `MyDerivedClass` type ?

Comment: The first one will be a better match, as it requires no derived to base convertion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is handled in section 13.3 of the standard. Paragraph 13.3/1 states:

> Each of these contexts defines the set of candidate functions and the
>   list of arguments in its own unique way. But, once the candidate
>   functions and argument lists have been identified, the selection of
>   the best function is the same in all cases: — First, a subset of the
>   candidate functions—those that have the proper number of arguments and
>   meet certain other conditions—is selected to form a set of viable
>   functions (13.3.2). **— Then the best viable function is selected based
>   on the implicit conversion sequences (13.3.3.1) needed to match each
>   argument to the corresponding parameter of each viable function.**

The first one is a better match since it won't involve any implicit conversion.

Comment: SFINAE can be done to block A, and is easy if you add a tag class to your template.