# Block a generic template function for all templated derived types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, overloading

This question follows this one : [Function overloading and template deduction priority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13900616/882932)

Considering the following classes :

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
class Base {};

class Derived0 : public Base<double, double> {};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
class Derived1 : public Base<T1, T2> {};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4> 
class Derived2 : public Base<T3, T4> {};
```

And the following functions :

```
template<typename T> f(const T& x); // version A
template<typename T1, typename T2> f(const Base<T1, T2>& x); // version B
```

My problem is that `f(double)` will call `version A` (ok), `f(Base<double, double>)` will call `version B` (ok), but `f(Derived1<double, double, double>)` will call `version A` (see the link to the other question at the beginning).

Using C++11, how to block `version A` and force `version B` for all derived members of `Base<T1, T2>` whatever `T1` and `T2` are ?

Note : If possible, I would like to avoid to add helper classes and prefer adding members to the provided classes.

Comment: something that is not fire-proof but that works in most cases and is short: http://codepad.org/HkfK7TfQ

Comment: What is T::Base ? The constructor ? (+ in what case it would'nt work) ?

Comment: `T::Base` is the inherited injected class name of `Base<T1, T2>` when `T` does not hide it by defining a member called `Base`. If `T` is itself `Base<T1, T2>`, then `T::Base` names the constructor (but SFINAE takes care that then `f` is ignored as well).

Comment: If I understand well, if T is derived from Base and no Base member has been provided in T, then it's the constructor which returns a type that is a base of T. So it works in all case, except if T has a member named Base() which is not a constructor. Do you confirm that ?

Comment: well I guess this was a bad idea, since it will also reject `namespace somewhereelse { struct Base {}; struct Derived : Base { }; }`, so I guess we should not consider using this trick. But, it does not name the constructor. It names the type. It only names the constructor if both the type before the `::` and after it are the same. I encourage you to add a new SO question if the details are still unclear to you.

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding well. If T = Derived0. What is Derived0::Base ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a trait that might work for you.

**The trait class:**

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename> struct Base { };

template <typename T> struct isbase
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef yes no[2];

    template <typename U, typename V> static yes & test(Base<U, V> const &);
    static no & test(...);

    static bool const value = sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

**Application:**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!isbase<T>::value>::type f(T const &)
{
    std::cout << "f(T const &)\n";
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void f(Base<T1, T2> const &)
{
    std::cout << "f(Base<T1, T2> const &)\n";
}
```

**Example:**

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct Derived1 : public Base<T1, T2> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << isbase<double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << isbase<Base<int, char>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << isbase<Derived1<bool, bool, bool>>::value << std::endl;

    f(double{});
    f(Base<int, char>{});
    f(Derived1<bool, float, long>{});
}
```

---

**Generalization:** We can make a more general trait to check if a type derives from a template instance:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Tmpl>
struct derives_from_template
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef yes no[2];

    template <typename ...Args> static yes & test(Tmpl<Args...> const &);
    static no & test(...);

    static bool const value = sizeof(test(std::declval<T>())) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Usage: `derives_from_template<T, Base>::value` etc.

Comment: Very good piece of code. Now, I'm searching how to do the same without a trait class for my particular application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give you `B` class template a marker type as member and cause instantiation of the general tempkate to fail when present. Normally, SFINAE works the other way around but using an indirection it should still work.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
class Base {
public:
    struct isBase {};
};

template <typename T>
struct is_base {
    template <typename S> char (&test(typename S::isBase*))[1];
    template <typename S> char (&test(...))[2];
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1 };
};

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_base<T>::value>::type f(T value) {
    ...
};
```

The solution basically does something similar to KerrekSB's solution but doesn't require explicit spelling out the supported types: It uses the tag `isBasd` (which should probably be spelled more unique) to detect objects of type `Base` or derived.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that, I'm not sure of understanding what you are describing ?